# NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance()

Tags: java, docx4j

This code:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(is);
FOSettings foSettings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
foSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);
Docx4J.toFO(foSettings, baos, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
//Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, baos);
```

Throws this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance()  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)    at
>   org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.createFopFactory(FORendererApacheFOP.java:335)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.getFopFactory(FORendererApacheFOP.java:253)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:119)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:168)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:47)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:82)
>     at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:575)

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, confirm that FOP 2.2 is on your path.

But from the stack trace, that doesn't look like export-fo v3.3.6, so please check your class path to ensure you don't have some earlier export-fo.